# Help with understanding a use of the Hahn Banach Theorem

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I am reading a proof regarding amenability of a group $G$ that includes the following:

Let $G$ be a group and let $X$ be a Banach space, $X^{*}$ its dual space, and $\pi$ an isometric representation of $G$ on $X$.
For all $x^{*} \in X^{*} $ we define a function:

$\mathcal{F}_{x^*}:X \to \mathbb{C} \hspace{0.5cm} \mathcal{F}_{x^*}(x)=m(\varphi_{x,x^*})$ where $m$ is a left invariant mean on $G$ and $\varphi_{x,x^*} \in L^{\infty}(G)$ such that $\varphi_{x,x^*}(g)=x^*\circ(\pi(x)(g))$

Around half way through the proof it says this:

Assume for a contradiction that for some $x^*$, $\mathcal{F}_{x^*}\notin$ conv$\overline{\{\pi^{*}(g)x^* : g \in G\}}^{\omega^*}$. By the Hahn-Banach Theorem there are $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and a $\omega^*$-continuous linear functional of $X^{*}$, say $x_{0}\in X$ (since $X^{**}\cong X$) such that Re$((\mathcal{F}_{x^*})(x_{0}))\leq a<b\leq$ Re$(\varphi_{x_{0}, x^{*}})$

I don't understand how the Hahn-Banach Theorem implies the above. I read the link in this post to find a detailed explanation of the Hahn_Banach Theorem: [Hahn–Banach theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048789/hahn-banach-theorem) but I don't see how it is being applied in this case. I would be really grateful if someone could explain it's use in this case!

Comment: I did not get full understanding of your above proof. However I feel 'Seperation Theorem' / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_separation_theorem / would be helped.

Comment: Can you confirm that $\pi$ denotes the group action (so that $\varphi_{x, x^*} =x^*(\pi(g)x)$); $\ \omega^*$ denotes the weak * topology on $X^*$; and $\mathcal P=\mathcal F$?

Comment: @Berci $\pi$ denotes an isometric representation of G on X, $\pi:G \to $Aut$(X)$. Yes $\omega^{*}$ denotes the weak* topology, and apologies I mixed up Ps and Fs! I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is making use of the geometric form of the Hahn-Banach theorem, sometimes called the 'separation theorem' as *Pseudo coder* commented. (These [notes](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/Func/notes/5-5.pdf) provide a fairly detailed explanation.)

Since $X^*$ is a Banach space, $\cal{F}_{x^*}$ is a point (and therefore closed) and $\mathrm{conv}\overline{\{\pi^*(g)x^* \mid g \in G\} } $ is a closed convex set we can apply the geometric form of the Hahn-Banach theorem which says that we can find a closed hyperplane $H=\{f^{**}=\alpha \}$ (for some number $\alpha$) that lies strictly between the two closed sets.  In particular, there must then be a linear functional (the one defining $H$ for certain) which takes on distinct values on the two closed sets, one less than $\alpha$ and one greater than $\alpha$.

So, choose $a<\alpha$ and $b>\alpha$ and you obtain the conclusion stated in your question.